# How to deal with ^C in JVM console applications?

Tags: java, scala, console, jvm, reliability

When a JVM-ran (written in Scala actually, but I tend to believe that the solution is going to be pretty much the same for Groovy, Clojure or pure Java) console program of mine gets terminated by the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or by the system shut-down sequence, I don't know if there is any difference for a program), how do I make sure the external resources the application modifies (databases, files, web service abstracted resources) are left in a predictable, non-logically-corrupt state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Runtime.addShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

You would typically use it as so:

```
Runtime.addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // do your clean up here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try to implement a shutdown hook as others pointed BUT:

> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may abort, that is, stop
>   running without shutting down cleanly. This occurs when the virtual
>   machine is terminated externally, for example with the SIGKILL signal
>   on Unix or the TerminateProcess call on Microsoft Windows. The virtual
>   machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example,
>   corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access
>   nonexistent memory. If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee
>   can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.

I guess, you would have to introduce transactional context into your application I believe. For databases that's quite easy, for file system you can look into [Apache Commons Transaction](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/)

Comment: +1 also the only way to secure a program against blackout and system crash.

Answer (score 3):

You can trap this signal and close off resources.  Most services do not need to be closed gracefully, however files you write to usually do.

It is possible just adding a shutdown hook is all you need. But I would test this for your situation.